# "Local Area Connection doesn't have a valid IP configuration

Tags: windows-7, networking

recently I got forced into a windows update when I was asleep and I went to go browse the internet this morning and got greeted with the lovely internet icon with an error sign on it. I've had this issue before on windows updates but the last time was 2 months ago and I forgot what actually fixed it. I've tried various solutions online such as Microsoftfixit and fidding around with the services msc and none seem to work.

Some side information
the computer that is experiencing this is connected via ICS from my laptop (both windows 7) which has fine internet so I have been without a gaming computer for a day due to the fact that I spent the good part of yesterday trying to fix it and I'm lost on what to do next

Any help/past fixes that worked for you are welcome!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you believe it was caused by the windows update just simple go to Control Panel --> Programs and Feature --> View installed Updates (at the left upper corner), sort it by date, right click and uninstall on the latest windows updates.

If you'd like to do windows update and apply security patches in the future make sure you install the updates one by one and check if it is compatible with your system.
If any of them is causing trouble just simple right click on them and "hide update"(in Windows update option).